# loading additional sd card on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: sd-card

hopefully this is the right place to ask this question.. 
I'm currently trying to add an additional micro SD card to a raspberry pi zero w. I am using the SPI1 interface with wiring as:

```
sd pin    rpi bcm pin
1         x 
2         17
3         20
4         3v3
5         21
6         GND
7         19
8         x
```

now when i boot i am using a custom device tree overlay to be able to enable the above spi configuration. the overlay looks like so:

```
//overlay for the sd card via SPI
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
   compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2836", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

   fragment@0 {
      target = <&spi1>;
      __overlay__ {
         #address-cells = <1>;
         #size-cells = <0>;

         status = "okay";

         sd1 {
                reg = <1>;
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "spi,mmc_spi";
                voltage-ranges = <3000 3500>;
                spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
                write-enable = "true";
         };
      };
   };
};
```

note that i am using spi1 and not spi0 and that i am also using reg<1> which i believe translates to chip enable 1 on the pi, ie pin bcm7 (physical pin 26)
now for the issue. when running the above setup, the sd card isnt initialised properly. i believe it is recognised but just wont fully load.

when calling dmesg | grep mmc after boot i get:

```
[   19.424206] mmc_spi spi1.1: /aliases ID not available
[   22.513097] mmc_spi spi1.1: SD/MMC host mmc2, no WP, no poweroff, cd polling
[   22.521078] mmc_spi spi1.1: no support for card's volts
[   22.521095] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[   22.528777] mmc_spi spi1.1: no support for card's volts
[   22.528796] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[   22.529914] mmc_spi spi1.1: no support for card's volts
[   22.529929] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising MMC card
[   26.676632] mmc_spi spi1.1: card claims to support voltages below defined range
[   29.084577] mmc2: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[   29.085042] mmc2: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[   29.116860] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[   29.119839] mmc_spi spi1.1: no support for card's volts
[   29.119850] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[   29.120941] mmc_spi spi1.1: no support for card's volts
[   29.120951] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising MMC card
[   33.236551] mmc_spi spi1.1: card claims to support voltages below defined range
[   33.246598] mmc2: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[   33.249492] mmc_spi spi1.1: card claims to support voltages below defined range
[   33.258145] mmc2: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[   33.258606] mmc2: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[   33.258632] mmc2: new SD card on SPI
```

I've spent 2 days on this already, any help or guidance on where to go next would be greatly appreciated
Also if anyone knows where i might find the error list for mmc that would also be a great help

Comment: No results so far?

Comment: unfortunately not. I ended up using a micro usb flash drive as the project was time constrained.

Comment: I had similar issue and it appears that MMC SPI doesn't work properly with DMA being enabled. I hacked out DMA and it magically started working. The idea was given by some thread and patch: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/790323/